# Hypotenuses for which there exist exactly 4 distinct integer triangles with an extra constraint

Tags: combinatorics, pythagorean-triples

A084648 of the OEIS contains all numbers where the square of the number can be decomposed exactly in four different ways in a sum of two squares of integers. For example 65 is a term of A084648 because:
$$65^2 = 16^2+63^2 = 25^2+60^2 = 33^2+56^2 = 39^2+52^2$$
I was searching for such a number where all 8 integers that form the 4 sums are also terms of A084648. I nearly found one:
$$49097^2 = 4695^2 + 48872^2 = 7072^2 + 48585^2 = 30305^2 + 38628^2 = 33860^2 + 35553^2$$
The squares of the first 7 numbers indeed can be decomposed exactly 4 times, but unfortunately 35553 is the hypotenuse of only one integer-sided triangle. My Python code gives overflow errors when I try larger numbers. Any suggestion?

Comment: I thought Python is impossible to overflow.

Answer (score 2):

Have this:
$$453041^2 = 38991^2+451360^2 = 138320^2+431409^2 =\\ = 250991^2+377160^2 = 282520^2+354159^2$$
(Yes this is the smallest example.)

I used Mathematica and its built-in functions for decomposing integers in sums of two squares, which is probably faster than we can do in Python.

Also, I only checked the numbers which are the products of two distinct primes of the form $4n+1$.

Comment: Your solution has the same problem as OP’s in that only $7$ of the $8$ terms decompose properly. 
$38991=3*41*417 $ has only one triple.  Only one of its distinct prime factors $\space (41)\space $ is a valid $C$-value.

Comment: $$38991^2 = 684^2+38985^2 = 8559^2 + 38040^2 = 9225^2+37884^2 = 17316^2+34935^2$$ Feel free to oppose this, or to add decompositions which I missed. Also, what is a triple? Also, what is a $C$-value?

Comment: Please forgive me for misreading 
$\space3\cdot41\cdot317$ as $\space3\cdot41\cdot417.\space $ I have cataract surgery later this month.
 You did a good job.

$$\\$$
A Pythagorean “triple” is an ordered set of integers
 $\big(A,B,C\big)$ where $A^2+B^2=C^2.\space$ The number $317$ is the $C$-value of the Pythagorean triple 
$\big(75,308,317\big)\quad $ and
 $3\times 41\times \big(75,308,317\big)
=\big(9225,37884,38991\big)$.

The reasoning for all this is in my answer to OP.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Since you only checked the numbers which are the products of two distinct primes of the form 4n+1, you are not testing numbers like $5^4$ or $13^4$, I will include them in my program, but now I know at least that at the latest at 453031 there must be a solution. Great work!

Comment: @Rüdi Jehn  A prime raised to any power points to a Pythagorean triple but only the number $\space n\space$ of distinct primes matter for the $2^{n-1}$ primitive triple count. For instance
$\quad 21125=5^3\times13^2\quad$ points to $6$ triples but only $2$ are primitive.


\begin{align*}
(3075,20900,21125)\quad  & GCD(25)\\
(8643,19276,21125)\quad  & GCD(1)\\
(12675,16900,21125)\quad &GCD(4225)\\
(19203,8804,21125)\quad   &GCD(1)\\
(19773,7436,21125)\quad   &GCD(169)\\
(20925,2900,21125)\quad   &GCD(25)
\end{align*}

Answer (score 0):

There are $\space 2^{p-1}$ primitive triples for every valid $C$-value where $\space n\space$ is the number of distinct prime factors of $\space C\space$ that are also valid $C$-values. For example, $\space 65=5\times13\space$ so there are
$\space2^{2-1}=2\space$
primitive triples  where $\space C=65.\quad $
There are also
$\quad 5\times(5,12,13)\space\text{and}\space 13\times(3,4,5)\quad$ where
$\space C=65.\quad $
Note: all $\space C$-values take the form
$\space4n+1\space$ but not all
$\space4n+1\space$ values are valid.

You can make Python use arbitrary precision as shown [here](https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-do-limitless-math-in-python-73f573570dfa) but perhaps you do not need to. The following will let you find  candidates fast without testing the square sums.

There is a way to use Euclid's formula to find primitives, doubles, square multiples, and doubles of square multiples of primitives but a faster way is by using a formula I developed
in $2009$ that generates/finds only and all triples where
$\space GCD(A,B,C)\space$ is and odd square.

\begin{align*}
A&=(2n-1)^2 &+2(2n-1)k&\\
B&=&2(2n-1)k&\quad +2k^2\\
C&=(2n-1)^2&+2(2n-1)k&\quad +2k^2\\
\end{align*}

To find triples for a give hypotenuse, we begin by solving the $\space C$-function for $\space k \space$ and testing a defined range of $n$-values to see which yield integers.

$$ C=(2n-1)^2+2(2n-1)k+2k^2\\
\implies k=\frac{\sqrt{2C-(2n-1)^2}-(2n-1)}{2}\\
\text{ for }1\le n \le\biggl\lfloor\frac{\sqrt{C-1}}{2}\biggr\rfloor\\$$
$$C=65\implies 1\le n\le\biggl\lfloor\frac{\sqrt{65-1}}{2}\biggr\rfloor= 4\\
\text{and we find}\quad
 n\in\{2,4\} \implies  k\in\{4,1\}  $$
$$ F(2,4)=(33,56,65)\quad F(4,1)=(63,16,65)$$
Doing the same for $\space C$-values $5$ and $!3$ yields $\space(3,4,5)\space$ and
$\space (5,12,13)\space $ which, multiplied by the cofactors of $ 65$, also yields $\space C=65.$

Let's take one of your terms where
$\space 7072 =2^5\times 13\times 17.\quad$
Since no power of $\space 2\space$ is a valid $\space C$-value, the $\space 2^{2-1}$ immediate  multiples of primitives we have are

$$32\times (21,220,221)\qquad 
32\times (171,140,221)$$

where $\quad 221=13\times17\quad $ and the other two are
$$2^5\times 13\times (15,8,17)\qquad 
2^5\times 17\times (5,12,13)$$

I can only imagine the complexity of the code needed to test so many things in nested loops but, if such a set of terms exists within say $\space 8\space$ digits, this will allow you to find them.